# ArcGIS Server Local edits

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, editing, feature-service

I'm having a problem with ArcGIS Server local edits. We have a feature service we use for multi-user editing and we use ArcMap 10.4 for creating a local copy and [synchronizing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/synchronizing-local-edits-with-the-server.htm) when we are done.

Problem is, as we all know, sometimes ArcMap crashes. This would not be a problem if the user would save the MXD so they can sync back when they are done but sometimes this is not done and we are met with a rather difficult situation.

A simple and rather raw way to fix this is to find the local copy in FeatureServiceLocalEdits and replace the data on the server with the current data.

This can lead to rather frustrating tasks and potential data loss.

**Is there a way to sync a local copy to ArcGIS Server after the group is lost?**